# How to write vector in vector in java

Tags: java, vector, indexoutofboundsexception

I used to write c++ like this vectorV[size] or vector> 
but I don't know how to write it in java. 
I tried to write like this Vector> x = new Vector>(size) but when I want to use it like this  x.get(index).add(new object) ,it will have an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException .How can I solve it ,help me plz ,thx.

Comment: Please show more of your non-working code. It would help if we could fully understand what you might be doing wrong.

Comment: You *probably* don't want a `Vector` because it is broken and garbage. Use an `ArrayList`

Comment: @Idos Would you mind explaining what is "broken and garbage" about a `Vector`?

Comment: Sure, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-is-java-vector-class-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated

Comment: @Idos The accepted answer is that you shouldn't use a Vector unless you want to have a synchronized implementation of List. Which is correct. And is something **completely** different than "broken and garbage". Btw you may want to respond to people by prefixing your comment with @ and their name, otherwise they don't see your response.

Comment: You can Google for further information, but the fact is that you **almost never** want to use `Vector`, and that is what I meant. We can argue over terminology but that doesn't really matter.

Comment: It is the first time that I use Stackoverflow and I really apprecitate that your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that you are able to allocate the C++ vector to initially contain `size` instances, where those elements are empty vectors.

```
auto vectorOfVectors = vector<vector<T>>(10);
cout << vectorOfVectors.size() << endl;  // Outputs 10.
```

You don't the same thing with Java Vector. Even if you construct it with a `capacity` parameter, all you are doing is asking for *space* for that many elements to be reserved in the vector. The vector's size is initially zero (unless you call the `Vector(Collection<? extends E>)` constructor with a non-empty collection as the parameter).

```
Vector<Vector<T>> vectorOfVectors = new Vector<>(10);
System.out.println(vectorOfVectors.size());  // Outputs 0.
```

If you want to allocate a vector with `size` elements, you need to do it explicitly:

```
Vector<Vector<T>> vectorOfVectors = new Vector<>(size);
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
  vectorOfVectors.add(new Vector<T>());
}
```

However, `Vector` is a strongly deprecated class. You probably want to be using `ArrayList` instead (in exactly the same way).

Comment: yes !Really thx a lot !

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, you need nested vector. You can use nested `ArrayList` in Java instead of that.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> arrayList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();
ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> al1 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();
ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> al2 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();
arrayList.add(al1);
arrayList.add(al2);
arrayList.get(0).add(new Object()); // retrieves al1
```

Tell me if you need clarification.

Comment: thx a lot .  write vector in vector in the same way!